# Cancel check after receiving response (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a check a question for "true" or "false" as the answer after the command. For example:

```
@client.command
async def thisisnotarealcommand(ctx):
channel = ctx.message.channel
await channel.send(f'Write "true" or "false":')
           def check(response):
               return response.content == "true" and response.channel == channel and response.author == ctx.author
           try:
               response = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=10,check=check)
```

Is it possible that after I receive an answer, it stops the command (and sends a message)? For example, if they say "false", it'll cancel the command before timing out (since you can just immediately answer "true" after)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think this is it.

```
if not response:
    break
```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to be working. One of the problems is that the `check` is waiting until it receives the right answer, and I want to cancel when it's the wrong answer. That way, you only have one chance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your issue. If you want you can add me on Discord @ starmoan#4269

Comment: Thanks! It says you're not accepting friend requests though. :)

Comment: That's odd, if you want you can just send me your Discord.

Comment: My Discord is AnorakX#8873. Thanks!